# How to get Ref current value react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've tried all the solutions from this link: [How to get values from input types using this.refs in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137275/how-to-get-values-from-input-types-using-this-refs-in-reactjs)

Everything from `ref.current.value` to `ref.value` to `ref._getText()`. Everything is undefined. I looked at the json'ed output of the ref object, and the only data members seem to be .clear and .isFocused. Is it no longer possible to get the current data value of a ref?

I am attaching a ref directly to a textInput, like so:

```
<TextInput
  ref = {itemRef}
/>
```

I am trying to access the current string text inside the text input.

Comment: ```ref.current```?

Comment: ref.current gets me a giant object

Comment: What are you trying to access from the object? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: Are you using react native ? then maybe -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35713280/4994352

Answer (score 0):

Its too late, But maybe can help someone else

```
<TextInput ref = {ref => (this.inputRef = ref)} />


const inputValue = this.inputRef.current.value;
console.log('Input Value:', inputValue);
```