# How to use ref inside a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I have a problem with class component. Is there anything like `useRef()` in class component? I have searched so many times, but it did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get values from input types using this.refs in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137275/how-to-get-values-from-input-types-using-this-refs-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called:

```js
React.createRef()
```

In your class Component, you can do e.g.:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs